# What was going to lift the components of Space Station Freedom?

Tags: history, space-station, construction

For the [Space Station Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Station_Freedom) (predecessor of ISS), what was the plan for lobbing the various components up into orbit? Was it going to be launched on a modified [Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V) like [Skylab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab) was, or were the components going to be designed to fit inside of the space shuttle, or would have something like the [STS-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle-C) been used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was planned to be launched piecemeal by the Shuttle.

One of the first redesigns was to reduce the number of Shuttle missions required.

> NASA tried to reduce the number of Shuttle assembly flights by making
>   several modifications. The first launch would now take place in March
>   1994, the Station would be permanently manned from April 1995 onwards
>   and be completed in March 1997 after 17 flights. Congress disliked the
>   6-9 month delay and briefly demanded that the schedule be accelerated.

[Reference](http://www.astronautix.com/s/spacestationfreedom.html)

You can see the influence of Freedom on what would become the ISS in this artist's concept.

[image]

Comment: Lots of on-orbit construction too.  Way too much.  That truss is built stick by stick tinker-toy fashion by astronauts on EVA.

Comment: @Erik https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Ease_assembly.jpg/297px-Ease_assembly.jpg

Comment: yup.  My first job out of school was designing lock joints for the truss.

Answer (score 5):

There were different concepts proposed, where a Shuttle-C, a cargo version of the Shuttle, would launch a large singular station. Shuttle-C was non-reusable and got way more payload compared to a regular Shuttle mission since the wings and cockpit are gone. Or put another way minimizing the non-cargo stuff, lets a Shuttle-C concept carry much more actual payload.

Otherwise it was a Shuttle launched station design.